# Is it necessary to close a channel when sending data is finished?

Tags: go, pipeline, channel

Here is my program.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func init() {
    fmt.Println("init function")
}

func main() {
    // gen number to naturals channel
    naturals := gen(1, 2, 3)
    // write the squars in a channel
    squar := dosquar(naturals)

    for p := range squar {
        fmt.Println("printer shows----- ", p)
    }
}

func gen(nums ...int) chan int {
    naturals := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for _, n := range nums {
            fmt.Println("generating number ", n)
            naturals <- n
            fmt.Println("generated number ", n)
        }
        //close(naturals)
    }()
    return naturals
}

func dosquar(naturals chan int) chan int {
    // write the squars the values
    squar := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for number := range naturals {
            fmt.Println("recieved number ", number)
            squar <- number * number
            fmt.Println("sent squar of number ", number*number)
        }
        //close(squar)
    }()
    return squar
}
```

It gives following error.

```
init function
generating number  1
generated number  1
generating number  2
recieved number  1
sent squar of number  1
recieved number  2
generated number  2
generating number  3
printer shows-----  1
printer shows-----  4
sent squar of number  4
recieved number  3
sent squar of number  9
printer shows-----  9
generated number  3
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
        /Users/siyaram/go/src/github.com/SrmHitter9062/go-pipeline/main.go:15 +0x127

goroutine 19 [chan receive]:
```

I expect it to be running as channels are being ranged.That leads me to a question that do we need to close the channel every time, when we are finished with them ?

Please somebody help clarifying why program is not working as expected.

Comment: it is not mandatory as the language give you the possiblity to write other kind of exit condition, though, this is a great capability of the language understood by everybody and designed for a purpose. It was made to help you.

Comment: the deadlock is expected given the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want, but a `range` loop over a channel won't exit until the channel is closed.